# XCode 15 simulator issue

Tags: ios-simulator, kotlin-multiplatform, xcode15

I am trying to build a KMM project. Was working absolutely fine until some setting was updated accidentally. Ever since then I am not able to run the app from XCode.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Failed to create directory '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iosApp-amwlrqlexdqhzoayjosrnyeayhdd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.app/Frameworks'
```

Since I am not an iOS dev nor have much experience with the XCode I don't have any idea what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1):

Update kotlin version in build.gradle.kts file of the project like this:

```
  plugins {
    //trick: for the same plugin versions in all sub-modules
    id("com.android.application").version("8.1.0").apply(false)
    id("com.android.library").version("8.1.0").apply(false)
    kotlin("android").version("1.9.10").apply(false)
    kotlin("multiplatform").version("1.9.10").apply(false)
   }
```

With this change, please also update the kotlin compiler extension version inside build.gralde.kts file of androidApp like this:

```
composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.3"
    }
```

This will fix the issue of build failure on Xcode15.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue. Turns out there was something with MacOS Senoma and was not clearing out older processes. Had to force stop those and restart the machine to get it working.